# Create a Dynamic table

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

I've built an interface between my .net application and SQL server
So what I've done, I query my user view but some fields are not visible in this view, so I'd like to know if there is a way to create a dynamic table via SP
I'll explain my wish with some code:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
            P.*,
            OC.OrganismeClient,
        INTO db.pjrep.NewTable ----> This table is create here
        FROM
            DB.pjrep.MSP_EpmProject_UserView P

        --> Organisme client
            LEFT JOIN
                    (
                    SELECT
                        EntityUID as ProjectUID,
                        CAST(MemberValue as NVARCHAR(255)) as OrganismeClient
                    FROM
                        DB.pjrep.[MSPCFPRJ_Table] AA
                        JOIN DB.pjrep.MSP_EpmLookupTable LT on LT.MemberUID = AA.LookupMemberUID 
                    )
                    OC on OC.ProjectUID = P.ProjectUID
```

so once it's done, I'd like to be able to do :

```
SELECT "FIELDS WHICH COME MY .NET INTERFACE"
FROM db.pjrep.NewTable
```

But it doesn't work, my stored procedure runs during a very long time (I let it run more than 15 minutes) and I don't have a lot of data in my current DB

Any idea of what could I do?

Comment: add specific tag

Comment: I might be misunderstanding, but it sounds like you're passing the fields you want to your SQL `SELECT` statement as parameters, or something? You shouldn't be. If you only want to display certain fields on screen, then resolve that in the application, if you're reusing an existing SP.

Comment: No in fact, I want to build a table with my SP, but I can't use the CREATE TABLE and define all fields because I want all field from my view and some field can be add by data coming from Project Server
So this is why I'd like to use Into but in my case, it didn't work

Comment: If the query is long running, you need to be asking about the performance; clearly there's something wrong there.

Comment: I feel like I gave a fair attempt to answer your question. Could you consider marking it as the answer, or at least give some feedback if it didn't help you?

Answer (score 0):

I just want to note that I agree with @Larnu about the performance. This seems like a tiny query and shouldn't be taking that long. I would look into making sure there isn't a cross join of some sort. The fact that you have DISTINCT tells me that you might actually be returning a ton of duplicate rows and distinct is required to remove them. Try running it without distinct to see.

That said, if you need to create a table in the SP, you can use dynamic SQL. This example has it as a parameter, so you would need to consider that it could be SQL injected. Otherwise you could just create the variable within the SP. Here is an example:

```
--create stored procedure
CREATE PROCEDURE pjrep.CreateTempTable
    @Table_Param VARCHAR(200)
AS

DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(MAX) = 
'
SELECT DISTINCT
            P.*,
            OC.OrganismeClient
        INTO pjrep.' + @Table_Param + '
        FROM
            pjrep.MSP_EpmProject_UserView P
            LEFT JOIN
                    (
                    SELECT
                        EntityUID as ProjectUID,
                        CAST(MemberValue as NVARCHAR(255)) as OrganismeClient
                    FROM
                        pjrep.[MSPCFPRJ_Table] AA
                        JOIN pjrep.MSP_EpmLookupTable LT on LT.MemberUID = AA.LookupMemberUID 
                    )
                    OC on OC.ProjectUID = P.ProjectUID'

EXEC sp_executesql @sql

go



--run stored procedure
EXEC pjrep.CreateTempTable 'NewTable'

--view results
SELECT * FROM pjrep.NewTable
```